# Angularjs - directive datepicke, modify css

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, datepicker

I m using this directive to show a date picker:

```
myApp.directive('jqdatepicker', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',

                onSelect: function(date) {
                    var ngModelName = this.attributes['ng-model'].value;

                    // if value for the specified ngModel is a property of 
                    // another object on the scope
                    if (ngModelName.indexOf(".") != -1) {
                        var objAttributes = ngModelName.split(".");
                        var lastAttribute = objAttributes.pop();
                        var partialObjString = objAttributes.join(".");
                        var partialObj = eval("scope." + partialObjString);

                        partialObj[lastAttribute] = date;
                    }
                    // if value for the specified ngModel is directly on the scope
                    else {
                        scope[ngModelName] = date;
                    }
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

I need to show it in a modal dialog. So i need to modify css in order to change the z-index :

```
datepicker.dropdown-menu{
  z-index:9999
}
```

I don't know how to put this css into my directive.
If anyone can help me...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

CSS can be modified using jQuery like this:

```
$(element).css('background','red');
```

In your case:

```
$(element).find('.dropdown-menu').css('z-index','9999');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I debug the javascript/css (developper tools with Chrome) i see that my calendar css is : element.style {
display: block;
top: 141px;
left: 471.09375px;
z-index: 10;
}, It appears that .dropdown-menu is not the one I should modify. What would be the right way to change z-index in my directive? I have tried $(element).css('z-index','9999'); but this doesn't work.

Comment: Depends on what element you want to do the changes. For example, you can try $(element).find('div').css('z-index','9999'); to apply the css on all divs under element. Change the 'div' selector to what you want to modify.

Comment: When i click on my input, the calendar is showing behind my modal. The html produced code when the calendar is showing is : <div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top" style="display: block; top: 141px; left: 471.09375px; z-index: 10;">...</div> I have tried your solutions, but z-index stays equal to 10. If I change it "in live" to 9999, the calendar shows perfectly, so I m pretty sure that z-index is the css value to change. But I didn't manage to do it for now.